# Stretching a image in iOS using colorWithPatternImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, stretching

I have a image like this: [image]. In iPad, when I place it with these code:

```
[separatorLineView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 430, 3)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"]];
```

In iPad, it shows up like this:

[image]

In iPhone, it works fine.

The code for iPhone looks like this:

```
[separatorLineView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 180, 3)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"]];
```

How to avoid the repetition? Must I use resizableImageWithCapInsets?

Need some guidance and suggestions..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the following method

```
-(UIImage *)imageResize :(UIImage*)img andResizeTo:(CGSize)newSize
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];

    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, scale);
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

now change your code as

```
[separatorLineView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 180, 3)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self imageResize :[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"] andResizeTo:separatorLineView.frame.size]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are correct use resizableImageWithCapInsets.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html

Comment: yes it might work. If not then increase the 12 value It should b a bit more the left & right padding

Comment: increased to 100 as well.. no change... UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,100,0,100);