# iOS 7 view background

Tags: objective-c, ios7, background-image

I have settings View which is a View Object under self.view.

I added the background image as: `self.settingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_bg__650x740.png"]];`

The problem is, it is having extra images at the bottom. This only happens in  iOS 7.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Please, help me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is being tiled. Why are you creating a tiled image and using it as a background color? Just put the image in a UIImageView and add the image view to the view.

Answer (score 0):

try resize your image before adding to background.

You can find answer in here
[Stretching a image in iOS using colorWithPatternImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705424/stretching-a-image-in-ios-using-colorwithpatternimage)

Answer (score 0):

the settings view's bound size is higher than the background color referred image. so, the image will tile to fill the settings view.