# how i can solve Image stretch in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I get image from web server and set imageview but not properly show. so please give me solution how is it work perfecly.[image]

**My Code is :**

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImageToSize:(UIImage *)BigImage
{
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = BigImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = imageSize.height;
    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetWidth, targetHeight);

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;    
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [BigImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    if(newImage == nil)
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    //[delegate resizeImageToSize:newImage];
    return newImage;
}
```

The image is not getting resized properly, can anyone suggest me where i am lacking behind.

Thanks

Comment: I saw your before question in stack overflow , your content mode is correct , I thing your image size is bigger or wider , try to convert resiziable image

Comment: i have no idea image is resiziable so pls give me instruction how is it work

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705424/stretching-a-image-in-ios-using-colorwithpatternimage

Comment: i have first use this type but not work then i can what to do

Comment: Can you show your relevant code to that so I can know better what you've done?